# Laravel hasManyThrough String Identifier

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here's what I've got:

```
Group
- id

User
- id
- group_id
- username

User Log
- id
- username
```

I'm trying to be able to setup the relationship to grab all the user logs for the group. That would be easy if there was a user id but there is not and that's not an option at this point. The username is the linking identifier. Here's what I've tried but this fails. I'm sure it's my last parameters but I don't know. Any help?

```
class Group extends Model {
    public function userlogs() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
             'App\UserLog'
            ,'App\User'
            ,'group_id'
            ,'username'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't user_logs have the foreign key `user_id` instead of `username`?

Comment: It doesn't. It's a native table from something else. But it does map by username.

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: @JanKaltoun It doesn't return any rows.

Comment: @dovidev according to documentation, there should be a 5th parameter too. `id` in your case. Could you try adding it?

Comment: @JanKaltoun I'll try that. Can you link me to the documentation you're speaking of? I couldn't find any that were very descriptive regarding parameters.

Comment: @JanKaltoun, That didn't change anything.